# How do I take screenshots of my UI with Xcode 7 during UI Testing?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

So I downloaded the beta of XCode 7 and I've created some UI tests, but I can't find the functionality of how to take screenshots of my app/UI during the test.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

UI Testing in Xcode automatically takes screenshots of your app after every step.

Simply go to one of the tests that has already ran (Report Navigator > choose a Test), then start expanding your tests. When you hover your mouse over the steps, you will see eye icons near each step that has a screenshot.

Here's an example... in this case, notice the eye icon at the end of the gray row. If I were to tap on it, I would see a screenshot of the app right when the button in my app was tapped (since the step is *Tap the "Button" Button*).

[image]

Comment: Does this work in XCode 7.1 ? I am not able to see the same. 

Also through this process, XCode will take screenshots for Failed test cases as well ?

Comment: In Xcode 7.1 right click on the test and select "Jump to report".

Comment: Is there a way to reference these screenshots from within the tests themselves? That would allow us to compare the result of an action to the desired result. Is that possible?

Comment: These eye icons are not appearing for me in Xcode 7.3beta5 (7D162j).

Comment: @LeMotJuiced This can be used to analyze the results of a test and figure out why it broke, but it can't be used for perceptual difference testing. The screenshot is not available to the test code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate screenshots, you can also use [snapshot](https://fastlane.tools/snapshot), which describes how to trigger screenshots in UI tests: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/snapshot#how-does-it-work

It basically rotates the device to `.Unknown` ([Source](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/snapshot/lib/assets/SnapshotHelper.swift#L100)), which triggers a snapshot without actually modifying your app's state.

Comparing the output with the generated plist file enables you to even properly name the screenshot

Comment: fastlane snapshot and deliver works great when generating app store screenshots. However I'm looking for a solution to generate a static website from snapshots which is targeted towards purely UITests. For example screenshots batches are separated based on test cases+devices+language. Can we have such a flavor in snapshot in future or do you know any alternative?

Comment: Can you not use `snapshot` for that?

Comment: I can. And of course I'm using `snapshot`. I just want a different template for generated static web page.(A separation of image batches based on the test) which I'm working on. I was wondering if there anything already available.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's [ios-snapshot-test-case](https://github.com/facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case) and [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) both run as Unit Tests, and therefore are in the same process as the app. As such, they can directly access views and use something like `renderView:` or `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`. Xcode UI Testing runs in a separate process, and therefore cannot directly access the views.

UI Automation, Apple's now-deprecated Javascript UI testing library, had a function called[`captureScreenWithName`](http://erence/UIATargetClassReference/#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/captureScreenWithName).

Unfortunately, the new Xcode UI Testing lacks any similar function in its testing library, which to me seems like a glaring omission and I encourage you to submit a Radar for it, as taking screenshots is fundamental to perceptual difference tests (which it sounds like you're trying to do). I hope (and expect) that able will address this deficiency in later Xcode updates.

In the meantime, there are more creative approaches to taking screenshots. See this stack overflow [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31513754/1016515) for a workaround involving taking the screenshot in the app itself and then sending it to the test process.

Answer (score 0):

I' ve created a tool that saves the tests last n screenshots and generates the JUnit tests results report, parsing TestSummaries plist file from test logs. https://github.com/nacuteodor/ProcessTestSummaries

Maybe, that helps you.

Comment: Can I ask you to take a look at [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085) please?

Answer (score -1):

Facebook's FBSnapshotTestCase can be alternative solution:

https://github.com/facebook/ios-snapshot-test-case