# Xcode UI test manual snapshot

Tags: ios, xctest, xcode7, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I want to manually take some snapshots from my applications using UI Tests intoduced in Xcode 7. By default, Xcode takes screenshots of every step and in result I got screenshots that was taken in the middle of transitions between view controllers. I want to manually take snapshot in the specific moments. Any ideas how to do this? I know how to take screenshot of UIView, but XCUIApplication doesn't provide any API to get UIView objects.

Comment: Check out [snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot), part of the Fastlane suite of tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a library for this: https://github.com/zmeyc/UITestUtils
The idea is to take the screenshot in the app itself and send it to the test app via sockets. I didn't find a way to capture screenshots in a controlled manner directly from the test app.

Comment: Nice, I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to install it via cocoapods?

Comment: Not yet, I'll look into it.